# How to make sync function from async in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, synchronization

I've a return type function:

```
var responseData = '';
function getResponseFromKey(key){

    client.get(key, function(err, reply){
        responseData = reply;
    });
    return responseData;
}
```

When I call this function first time it returns blank and then second time returns my value what I want after running again.

I'm calling this function to print in html page.

```
http.createServer(function(request, response){
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
    getResponseFromKey("my_key");   
    console.log(responseData);
}).listen(8083);
```

As I'm familiar with node the function is going in asynchronous way. Can you please help me to make synchronous way? Do I need to use `generators` in that case?

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can use `callbacks`, `promises` or `generators`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: You should use promise  js .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your client.get function is async try returing return responseData; inside the client.get body

```
var responseData = '';
 function getResponseFromKey(key ,cb){

 client.get(key, function(err, reply){
    responseData = reply;
    return cb(responseData);
 });

}

http.createServer(function(request, response){
 response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
 getResponseFromKey("my_key", function(responseData) {
  console.log(responseData);
});   
}).listen(8083);
```

Comment: I'm getting this error while running your code `TypeError: cb is not a function`

Comment: have you written this correcty  getResponseFromKey("my_key", function(responseData) {
  console.log(responseData);
});

Comment: callback is the second parameter in a function call.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `callback`, `promise` or `generator`.

Using callback, you need to send a callback function and call it instead of returning a value

```
function getResponseFromKey(key, callback){
  client.get(key, function(err, reply){
    callback(reply);   
  });
}

http.createServer(function(request, response){
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
  getResponseFromKey("my_key", function() {
    console.log(responseData);
  });   
}).listen(8083);
```

Using promise, you need to return a Promise

```
function getResponseFromKey(key) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    client.get(key, function(err, reply) {
      return resolve(reply);   
    });
  })
}

http.createServer(function(request, response){
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
  getResponseFromKey("my_key").then(function(responseData) {
    console.log(responseData);
  });   
}).listen(8083);
```

If you are using and up-to-date version of nodejs, you can use arrow functions, to make your code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

In many case, the callback is not a good choose.

You can use `async`,`promises`,`generators` and `async functions which supported in es7`.

I recommend `promises` beacuse the [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) a key features in ES6.

I think this article will help you.

https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-async-best-practices-avoiding-callback-hell-node-js-at-scale/